# Return error in JSON body from webapplicationexception

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am trying to put my error message inside the body of an `WebApplicationException`.
I get the status code in postman but the body remains empty.

I have tried to add a mapper like this

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class UnexpectedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    private static final transient ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final Exception exception) {
        ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity(defaultJSON(exception))
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return builder.build();
    }

    private String defaultJSON(final Exception exception) {
        ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo(exception.getMessage(), exception.getMessage());

        try {
            return MAPPER.writeValueAsString(errorInfo);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            return "{\"message\":\"An internal error occurred\"}";
        }
    }
}
```

But postman still tells me the body remains empty when I throw the error.

```
throw new Exception("test")
```

Is there a better way and why isn't this working?
The status gets updated but no body is passed with info in it.

The reason I need this is because I want to pass along the error that I get from another endpoint that I am calling.

EDIT:
I am also trying a simple Response version
but when i throw an error the entity is ignored as well

```
  Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity("Does not work").build();
  Response.status(Response.Status.SEE_OTHER).entity("Does work").build();
```

I am throwing it like this for testing atm.

```
 @POST
    @Path("/place/actionid/{nr}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getActionIdForPlaceAssetOrder(@PathParam("nr") @Valid String nr, @Valid Body body) throws Exception {
        Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity("Some message here").build();

        return response;
```

The above code throws the status but ignores the message. like i said any error message gets ignored. Is this maybe a jetty issue?
At the moment i would just be happy if i can get any message passed to postman.

Comment: Did you verify that your `ExceptionMapper` is even invoked? Possible issues are that it's not discovered by the JAX-RS runtime (although `@Provider` annotation should be enough) or there is a more specific `ExceptionMapper` which get invoked (i.e. `ExceptionMapper<MyException>`)

Comment: Please include the code throwing the exception, including any `try...catch` constructs, if any.

Comment: The mapper is invoked because the the status code changes. the issue is that any error code does not pass the message to the body. that way i even tried a simple response version. and in that case the same thing happens. I am decently new to java but it seems that any error status ignores the entity and i dont know why.

Comment: there are security settings in java, that prevent to return body in exceptions to the client. Try to google about it.